# Weird Chrome debugger behavior

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I've been having a lot of issues with chrome debugger. Sometimes I can't enable breakpoints at certain positions, other issues include random pauses at lines without breakpoints, can't evaluate variables that are absolutely defined.

The most weird thing I've seen, and am eager to work around, is the following:

[image]

I reached here from an event listener breakpoint, as one can see in the right pane. At first I put a breakpoint at line 4121 where I want to see what `elem` is. It can't be evaluated, saying it's undefined.

Now I commented out everything. It still hits the code. Notice the highlighted region. It's not my selection. It's the code that's yet to be executed. The highlight does not make any sense.

What can I do to get better debugging experience?

EDIT: I just tried with Firefox, to my surprise it behaviors almost the same with Chrome (i.e. hit the commented out code). There might be some rational explanations to this.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The information in the Call Stack and Scope panel doesn't match what is in the code where it is paused. Your app is running with a minified version of jQuery, but the uncompressed version is shown in Sources.

You should see the following in those panels if you are running the uncompressed version on it's own. If you use the minified version, you should see what you already have, but the Sources view will show the minified version, unless you have the Source Map configured. Since it appears you commented out the code in the uncompressed version, you're probably not using Source Maps.

**Side note:** If you do use Source Maps and edit the minified version, you would have to regenerate the map, otherwise the mappings will be all wrong.

[image: Source Maps]

That makes me think it's more likely to be an issue caused by having multiple references to jQuery. Make sure you only have one reference to jQuery in your solution, otherwise you can't guarantee which version is loaded at a given time.

Comment: Thanks! I'm convinced by your answer. I'm on some other business these days and might not verify your answer very soon. I'm marking your answer as accepted for now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If you have made edits to the Javascript in Dev Tools you will need to <kbd>ctr</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> (Save) the edits before you can enable breakpoints.

Comment: If the file is unsaved, it will have an asterisk (*) next to the name in the tab. This doesn't appear to be the case.